# Существуют ли плагин, который позволил бы в постах заменять URL ссылки?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, cms, wordpress-плагины

Существуют ли плагин или другие подобные инструменты, которые позволили бы в постах заменить URL ссылок.

Т.е. напрмер есть на сайте 100 постов, в которых в тесте есть ссылка на http://google.ru

Нужен такой плагин, с помощью которого можно бы было найти все такие посты и заменить в них эту ссылку на другую, которую пользователь указывать будет сам. По сути вместо http://google.ru вставить http://yandex.ru и во всех постах таких оно должно замениться.

Comment: https://github.com/mxkh/url-finder

Comment: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/